# Subscribe button is not showed up for an published API using WSO2 AM 1.9

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I published one API using [Publisher API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Publisher+API). 
While adding API I had added subcriptions like below :
`default_version_checked=default_version, tiersCollection=Unlimited,Gold,Silver,Bronze, transport_http=http, transport_https=https, inSequence=none, outSequence=none, faultSequence=none, responseCache=Disabled, **subscriptions=all_tenants**,` ...........

While publishing I had added below query param as well:

```
action=updateStatus, name=xxxxx, version=1.0, provider=admin, status=PUBLISHED, publishToGateway=true, **subscriptions=all_tenants**
```

The API is showing good in Publisher Ui as well as STORE UI, but there is **no subscription button** for that published API! I tested with old and new consumer as well.

I am surprised. Anything more I need to add for the subcription flow? More over I could not found any "Subcription" management option like (all tenant/current tenant/..) for WSO2 AM 1.9; it was there for AM 1.8.

Can anyone please help me to enable subcribe button in API store?

Comment: Hi All, I got the answer by debugging my code. It is not related to to any tag mentioned above. It is actually related to one query param "advertiseOnly". If I use advertiseOnly=true, it is not allowing to subscribe; it  is like advirtising. When I use "advertiseOnly=false", subscribe button is showing. Problem solved.

Thank you @Abimaran for modifying this properly.

Comment: Add the above comment as answer. I will try to find the reason for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer by debugging my code. 
It is not related to to any tag mentioned above. 
It is actually related to one query param `"advertiseOnly"`. 
If I use advertiseOnly=true, it is not allowing to subscribe; it is like advertising. 
When I use `"advertiseOnly=false"`, subscribe button is showing. Problem solved.